# Call another method in Spring Aspect

Tags: spring-aop

I would like to convert a parameter and then call second method with this parameter.
The convention would be that there is always the same method overloaded with the specific type. The idea is to solve it with Spring AOP.

```java
@Component
public class ExampleAspect {

  @Around( "@annotation(Example)" )
  public Object test( final ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint ) throws Throwable {
    final MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature) joinPoint.getSignature();

    final Method method = signature.getMethod();

    final Example example = method.getAnnotation( Example.class );
    final Object[] args = joinPoint.getArgs();
    final String test = args[example.value()].toString();
    final Bar bar = convertToBar(test)
    args[example.value()] = bar;

    //ReflectionUtils?
    // call getBar(Bar bar)
    //return joinPoint.proceed( args );
  }
}
```

Here is the service

```java
  @Example(0)
  public Object getBar(String test) {}

  public Object getBar(Bar test) {}
```

Are there any better options or ideas?

EDIT:

Cannot inject the target bean, because this AOP should be used by more than specific target bean.

1 possible solution not sure if there is a smarter solution

```java
  @Around("@annotation(Example)")
  public Object test(final ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    final MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature) joinPoint.getSignature();
    final Method method = signature.getMethod();

    final Example example = method.getAnnotation(Example.class);
    final Object[] args = joinPoint.getArgs();
    final String bar = args[example.value()].toString();
    final Bar aspectModelUrn = convertFromStringToBar(bar);
    args[example.value()] = bar;

    final Class<?>[] parameterTypes = method.getParameterTypes();
    parameterTypes[example.value()] = Bar.class;
    final Method newMethod = ReflectionUtils.findMethod(joinPoint.getTarget().getClass(), method.getName(), parameterTypes);
    if (newMethod == null) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("There is no method blubb. Have you forget to create the delegate method");
    }

    return newMethod.invoke(joinPoint.getTarget(), args);
  }
```

Comment: This is a perfect example for the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/309898): You are describing an idea **how** to technically want to solve a problem instead of explaining **what** kind of problem you are actually trying to solve. I think your idea is particularly bad, both from a general design perspective (you really should work with interfaces like R.G said) and from an AOP one (your annotations scatter technical AOP logic details across the application classes, thwarting the very purpose of AOP to do the opposite).

Comment: BTW, your aspect skips invoking the original method. Is that really what you want? If so, why does the original method exist at all, if its only purpose is to be replaced by a call to an overloaded version of itself, using your contrived "solution" with an extra annotation and AOP instead of simply calling the other method by itself, as is customary for overloaded methods? This (IMO) abuse of AOP borders on self-encryption, as much as I love AOP in general. Instead of presenting your solution, please show more code to better explain the actual problem, please.

Comment: The original idea was to overload the method and to skip and replace the original method. But yeah that looks like bad design and I'd rather discard the idea

Answer (score 1):

Following code would provide a handle to the annotation and the target bean (for example , here `TestComponent`)

A call to the `TestComponent.getBar()` annotated with `@Example` would be intercepted and advised.

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class ExampleAspect {

    @Around("@annotation(example) && target(bean)")
    public Object test(final ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint,Example example,TestComponent bean) throws Throwable {
        String value = String.valueOf(example.value());
        Bar bar = convertToBar(value);
        bean.getBar(bar);
        return joinPoint.proceed();
    }
}
```

Do go through Spring AOP documentation : [Passing Parameters to Advice](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop-ataspectj-advice-params-passing) for more details.

Note : For better performance it is a good idea to limit the scope of the expression as follows.

`@Around("@annotation(example) && within(com.xyz.service..*) && target(bean)")`

where `com.xyz.service..*` will limit the expression scope only to the beans with in the package `com.xyz.service..*` and its sub-packages.

Comment: Nice thanks explanation. The issue is the target bean can be different, so iam looking for a more general solution, because this conversion are in different classes and therefore i would create this AOP.

Can i skip the original method call and just return the result from the second method?
Any disadvantages ?
 return bean.getBar(bar);

Comment: The original method call can be skipped . As a suggestion , wouldn't it be easier to implement a common interface method for this fallback logic ?

Comment: Yes but in your case you call the joinpoint correct? So i have to change this 'return joinPoint.proceed();'

Yes it would be easier, but i think i cannot create a common interface, because the method parameter can be on different index or order. Therefore is the value on the annotation

Comment: Yes. I see . My knowledge is limited to ReflectionUtils in that case.

Comment: I added a possible solution, maybe someone find a smarter one :-)